# How to setup database tables with multiple similar attributes

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

There are products, sections and attributes.

Each attribute can have up to 5 or 6 options.

Example: Power

```
10 Volt
15 Volt
20 Volt
```

And there are about 10 products in total, each product has up to 17 attributes applied to it.

Example: Product 1

```
power - 10 volt
color - red, yellow
link - online, offline
```

How would you setup the tables? Im stumped. I was thinking of having a separate table for each attrubute, then a products table and sections table.

The products table would house foreign keys for the attributes that relate to it and sections. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are the sections groups of related products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite common.  You can have a base product table with some general attributes like...

```
Product
-------
ProductID
ProductName 
Description
Price
```

Then you can extend the table for different product types.  So you could have a table like

```
ProductElectrical 
-----------------
ProductID
Voltage
Watts
BatterySize
```

Or...

```
ProductApparel
---------------
ProductID
Color
Size
Material
```

Then when needed you can join the extension tables to the core product table like this...

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.Description, pa.Color, pa.Size, pa.Material
from Product p
join ProductApparel pa
on pa.ProductID = p.ProductID
where pa.Size = "XXL"
```

This way you can have a compact core product table used throughout your system.  When you need to see the extra attributes you can easily join them to the core Product table.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of having a separate
>   table for each attrubute,

Don't create a separate table for each attribute, this won't server your purpose.

Create separate tables for each of the products, sections and attributes and join them accordingly using PKs and FKs.

Comment: Hmm that was my first thought. But I worry that the attributes table it going to get out on control

Comment: @jrutter: no, it shouln't, you need to identify each attribute with corresponding FK of product in the same table and more than one record(attribute) could be inserted for a product. Thanks....